# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a fairly simple timer event that decrements the opacity of all the elements in an array of objects:

```
public function onShadowFade(timerEvent:TimerEvent):void
    {
        for each (var newShadow:Shadow in shadows) 
        {
            newShadow.alpha -= 0.02;

            if (newShadow.alpha <= 0)
            {
                newShadow.parent.removeChild(newShadow);
            }
        }
    }
```

This gets the following error message ever attempt:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

As far as I am aware, this issue can be caused by the following:

- Not declaring the instance (I do that at the start of my class)
- Misspelling the instance name and so referencing an undefined object (Checked)

I am not sure what is causing this issue.

In an attempt to debug the issue I added a line of code to trace my array - shadows - every run:

```
trace(shadows);
```

This returns a list similar to this:

> [object Shadow],[object Shadow],[object Shadow] etc.

I think this proves that the objects I am referencing are not null objects so what else is wrong?

**Added Information**

The shadow objects are created using this code:

```
var newShadow:Shadow = new Shadow();
shadows.push(newShadow);
newShadow.x = shadowX;
newShadow.y = shadowY;
addChild(newShadow);
```

Comment: Have you checked that all newShadow's have a .parent ?

Comment: @AlexK. They are all set as children of the controller movie clip when they are created. When I use `trace(newShadow.parent);` it returns `[Object PlayScreenController]`

Comment: Do you have the debug version of Flash Player? It'll tell you the line of error.

Comment: Did you simplify the code to show it here? Are you sure this function is the error location?

Comment: doing stuff with parent never really pans out, how about you send a custom event to your parent, and he removes the child from his displaylist himself?

Comment: @DodgerThud The parent is the one running this code. I just use that method of reference because I find it more realisable. I tried your method too and it results in the same error.

Comment: @SamDeHaan Commenting out that line removes the error so I can only assume that that is it.

Comment: @TreeTree I don't think I do. I have fair evidence to suggest that that is the troubling line though.

Comment: out of interest, could you make a method in the parent, void test() or whatever with a trace in it, and call it through the child with casting? i.e. (newShadow.parent as YourParentClass).test() and see if you get a trace?

Comment: Oddly I get an error saying that I am referencing an undefined method. What could that mean?

Comment: Does it do that right away or do you get traces at the beginning? i think you have to remove the shadow not only from the displaylist, but from the array as well. otherwise the next time the for loop checks, alpha on this particular shadow will still be <= 0 and he will try to remove something that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: also, before you try to remove it, make another if condintional like if(parent.contains(shadow)){remove it}. and you might as well trace the value of contains() anyway to see if it exists on the displaylist of the parent at all.

Comment: @DodgerThud Ah yeah! That's it. It was still trying to remove instances that were in the array. Works perfectly now. Thanks for the hand.

Comment: glad to be able to help. do you mind if i put it up as an answer?

Comment: Sure. Knock yourself out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to remove an DisplayObject although it might not exist anymore.

To avoid this, you have two options

1. remove it from the array and then remove it from the displaylist
2. Check if it is still in the displaylist with contains(...) and only remove it if it exists.

Like this, essentially.

Option 1)

```
if (newShadow.alpha <= 0)
            {
                shadows.splice(IndexOf(newShadow), 1);
                newShadow.parent.removeChild(newShadow);
            }
```

Option 2)

```
if (newShadow.alpha <= 0)
        {
            if(newShadow.parent.contains(newShadow){
               newShadow.parent.removeChild(newShadow);
            }
        }
```